# Como 'explodir' a coluna CIDADE EXECUÇÃO do DF, transformando cada lista em uma linha separada, usando explode()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/jrbon/PROJETOS.xlsx', sheet_name='EM EXECUÇÃO', usecols= ['Nº SLIE/SLI', 'CIDADE EXECUÇÃO'])

#df = df.assign(Nº SLIE/SLI' = df['Nº SLIE/SLI''].str.split(',')).explode('Nº SLIE/SLI'')
#df.head(10)

newdf = pd.DataFrame(df)

newdf = df.explode('Nº SLIE/SLI')
newdf.head(12)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A saída desejada seria essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os comandos em comentário estão quase certos... Veja resposta

Comment: Olá Kaique. Agradecido, valeu pela força.

Answer (score -1):

Siga os passos abaixo:

### Criando base de teste

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": ["banana", "goiaba,morango", "abacaxi"]})

df
   A               B
0  1          banana
1  2  goiaba,morango
2  3         abacaxi
```

### Transformando string em lista e explodingo a lista em linhas

```
df = df.assign(B=df["B"].str.split(",")).explode("B")

df
   A        B
0  1   banana
1  2   goiaba
1  2  morango
2  3  abacaxi
```

Comment: Paulo bom dia. Agradecido pela força.